# Dist folder in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on small projects using VS code and I happen to see from time to time a little folder at the top of the code editor with all of the subfolders in my code. It looks like this. I have deleted it a few times but it seems to reappear. Dist in VS Code

[image]

Comment: IMHO, you would want to see this folder; it's your `build` output.

Answer (score 0):

"Dist" stands for "Distribution".
In this folder will appear result of `ng build` command.